# Получить сокращенное название месяца PHP?

Tags: php

В базе значение хранится в формате DATE: 2014-07-20
Как в PHP можно получить значение месяца в сокращенной форме?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выбирайте что хотите:

```
$time = strtotime('2014-07-20');

echo 'Месяц (сокращенное название) - '.date('M', $time).'<br>';  // Jul
echo 'Месяц (полное название) - '.date('F', $time).'<br>';  // July
echo 'Номер месяца c ведущим нулем - '.date('m', $time).'<br>'; // 07
echo 'Номер месяца без ведущего нуля - '.date('n', $time).'<br>'; // 7
```

Answer (score 3):

Вы читали документацию функции [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php)?

> `M Сокращенное наименование месяца, 3 символа  от Jan до Dec`

Comment: Надо получить из даты 2014-07-20, а не от текущей даты

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk - прочитайте ВНИМАТЕЛЬНО документацию, в которой сказано:

>Второй параметр функции  `int $timestamp = time()`. Используется метка времени, заданная аргументом timestamp, или текущее системное время, если `timestamp` не задан. Таким образом, `timestamp` является необязательным и по умолчанию равен значению, возвращаемому функцией `time()`.

Comment: Может так:
     date("M", mktime(0, 0, 0, $exp[2], $exp[1], $exp[0]));

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk - если вы не знаете как из даты 2014-07-20 получить метку timestamp, то вам поможет функция strtotime()

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk - код на [`Ideone.com`][1]


[1]: http://ideone.com/bQn3Rd

Comment: Тогда выходит так:
     date('d - m - Y',strtotime('2014-07-29'));

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk - зачем вы пишите `'d - m - Y'`, если вам нужно получить название месяца? Я выше привел ссылку на код.